# What does nextState do in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

In the React lifecycle function [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), nextProps is self explanatory.

But what does nextState do?

It doesn't sound right that I can evaluate upcoming state before even deciding if the component should be rendered/modified or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the state is already changed at that point and do you deem it necessary to rerender the component and based on that you return true or false

Answer (score 5):

`nextState` is for detecting if the component should update based on the upcoming state just like you mentioned.

This helps to optimize updating components.  For example:

If state becomes a large object with several properties, but a specific component only cares about a single property or a small portion of the state, you can check for that change to determine if the component needs to re-render.  This example was taken from the React documentation but does a good job of getting the point across:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.color !== nextProps.color) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.state.count !== nextState.count) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```